# Example of initial ideal

Tags: ideals, groebner-basis, monomial-ideals, monomial-order

I have a problem with understand some example, which I present below.

Let ideal $I = (x_1^2 + 3x_1x_2, 2x_1^2 + x_2^2)$. The initial monomial of both generators
is $x_1^2$. However, twice the first generator minus the second generator, we obtain $6x_1x_2 +x_2^2$. Up to this point I understand.

But why it has initial monomial $x_1 x_2$? I though that it has   initial monomial $6x_1 x_2$. Why we don't have $6$ constant?

And next I don't understand this part:
No linear combination with constant coefficients of the generators
has smaller initial monomial, so $in(I)_2 = (x_1^2, x_1x_2)$. Why $in(I)_2$ has above form?

Then, it is automatic that $in(I)_3$ contains $(x_1 ^3, x_1 ^2x_2, x_1x_2^2)$, but by direct computation we can find an element of $I$
which is equal to $x_2^3$, and thus has initial monomial $x_2^3$. Thus $in(I) = (x_1,x_2)^3$, and $in(I) = (x_1^2,x_1x_2,x_2^3)$.

And why $in(I)_3$ is not contain $(x_1 ^3, x_1 ^2x_2, x_1x_2^2, x_2^3)$? And why initial monomial is $x_2^3$?

Definition:
If $f \in S^kV$ is a homogeneous polynomial, write $f = \sum_I a_Ix^I$. Let
$I_m = max({I | a_I \neq O})$.
Initial monomial of $f$ is $in(f) = x^{I_m}$.
If $I \subset S$ is a homogeneous ideal, then the initial ideal of $I$ is the ideal $in(I)$ generated by ${in(f) | f \in I}$.

It comes from https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-0346-0329-4.pdf
Proposition 1.11

Comment: You say (regarding $x_1^2+3x_1x_2,2x_1^2+x_2^2$) "The initial monomial of both generators is $x_1^2$", but also (regarding $6x_1x_2+x_2^2$) "But why it has initial monomial $x_1x_2$?" I though that it has initial monomial $6x_1x_2$. Why we don't have $6$ constant?" Why do you not find the constant factor a problem in the first case?

Comment: In standard terminology, the constant factor is part of a monomial, and so the leading monomial of, say $2x_1^2 + x_2^2$ (assuming the order has $x_1 > x_2$) is $2x_1^2$. As generator for a (monomial) ideal, you can leave out the $2$, since it generates the same ideal anyway.